# Laravel - Difference between an authentication guard and driver?

Tags: laravel, lumen

What is the difference between an authentication guard and driver?

Can you extend guards, or can you only extend drivers?

Going through the framework, it seems like guards are just aliases, and drivers do the actual authentication...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree, this is a bit confusing.

First of all, there's no `Driver` class in Laravel at all.

There's `Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Guard` interface (implemented by `TokenGuard` and `SessionGuard`).
Basically, `Guard` defines how user credentials are retrieved (via session or token).

If you look at `Illuminate\Auth\AuthManager`, there are methods `createSessionDriver()` and `createTokenDriver()` which return `SessionGuard` and `TokenGuard` accordingly.

So yes, "driver" equals "guard" in terms of `AuthManager`.